# Finding the geolocation of center point between two known locations

Tags: geolocation

I am developing a web tool that shift the center of a radius when users are added to a grouping.  So I know the geolocations of two points and the distance between them.  I need to find the location of center between them.  This is done outside of a page displaying a map.  I am using google maps throughout the site, but I cannot find a way using the map api to get the coordinates of center.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to get the co ordinates of each point and performing some calculation of your own to find the centroid point and then map that? If that is the case i guess all you have to do is figure out how to map the co ordinates using the api. If google doesn't provide a way to find the center of many points in its api then you should be able to do the calculation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use this JS code to calculate the halfway point between two coordinates.

```js
const coordinates1 = '36.78117453647814, 31.42609083801402'
const coordinates2 = '36.85276578523889, 30.75743072081495'

const splitCoordinates1 = coordinates1.split(', ')
const latitude1 = parseFloat(splitCoordinates1[0])
const longitude1 = parseFloat(splitCoordinates1[1])

const splitCoordinates2 = coordinates2.split(', ')
const latitude2 = parseFloat(splitCoordinates2[0])
const longitude2 = parseFloat(splitCoordinates2[1])

const halfwayLatitude = (latitude1 + latitude2) / 2
const halfwayLongitude = (longitude1 + longitude2) / 2
const newCoordinates = `${halfwayLatitude}, ${halfwayLongitude}`

console.log(newCoordinates)
// 36.81697016085852, 31.091760779414486
```